# The Stereo Mode of my Headphones Can't be Activated on Windows 11

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-11, headphones, stereo

I have a problem since I installed Windows 11. The sound of my headphones suck. So I looked at a lot of forums to understand the problem.

What I understood is that on Windows 10 there were like two devices (stereo and hand-free) but since Windows 11 they are grouped together.

And the solution will be to go in the "sound" panel then in the microphone tab and inactivate our headphones to force stereo mode. The problem being the following: the stereo mode appears well but can't be activated. (my headphones are `AIAIAI tm2` (the brand, shown in colors).

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Sound]
[image: device Manager]
[image: Microphone]

Comment: In any OS there are always "like" two devices, profiles actually, for all similar headphones with microphone. It has been this way since ever. The first troubleshooting step should be remove and pair again. Also make sure your OS is fully updated (it may need to download additional drivers for A2DP, the HiFi Stereo profile without microphone.

Comment: First TY for your answer, I already try to remove and pair again the headphones. Do you know where I can download drivers for A2DP ? I don't know about this subject

Comment: A2DP is BT, so what you need is BT drivers, for Windows 11 for your system. You didn’t provide us information to help you find those drivers.

Comment: Hooo ok, what information do you need about my setup to know what drivers is good for me ?

Comment: Windows update *should* do it automatically so, again, make sure it is fully updated, then disable the microphone and headset and select the not headset profile.

Comment: I have already checked several times that windows is updated but nothing changes.

Comment: Identify your BT controller

Comment: This is my setup : 
motherboard MSI MAG B550 TOMAHAWK - B550/AM4/ATX
processor AMD Ryzen 7 3700X - 4.4GHz/36Mo/AM4/BOX
Graphic card MSI RTX 3070 VENTUS 2X OC - RTX3070/8Go/HDMI/DP
Network card Gigabyte PCI-E BT5/WiFi AC - GC-WB1733D-I

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same issue. I can't use an external mic + stereo output on discord, it only shows me the LE option as the sole device. Seems like a "better user experience" but I can't tweak it.

Comment: I have this problem as well, any BT headset will only appear as hands-free, with the telephone sound quality, and stereo is "disconnected" and can't be selected. It did actually work at some point but has been like this for years, since Windows 10, and the issue has persisted through the W11 update. Have never been able to resolve it. Using the 3rd party LDAC AD2P driver from Bluetooth Goodies does actually work, but my system can't support LDAC above 330k when using a BT mouse/keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I have no source for this, but it seems like windows is trying to be helpful by only showing the user a single combined device in most of its menus.

However, if you go to Settings > System > Sound > More sound settings > Recording, you can disable the *headset*/low energy part individually to stop it auto-switching to BT LE:

[image: Disabling a headset in windows settings]